# How to make windeployqt include only the needed modules?

Tags: qt, dll, windeployqt

Due to concerns with some Qt libraries with GPL licenses(most are LGPL available), we removed most unused dependencies on our project. After running windeployqt:

```
windeployqt.exe --dir setup --compiler-runtime --release --qmldir ..\Qml ..\release\OUREXE.exe
```

We get following logs:

```
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5WebSockets Qt5Widgets    Qt5WebEngineCore Qt5WebEngineWidgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DInput Qt53DExtras
All dependencies   : Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core Qt5Gamepad Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Positioning Qt5PrintSupport Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5QuickWidgets Qt5WebSockets Qt5Widgets Qt5WinExtras Qt5WebEngineCore Qt5WebEngineWidgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DQuick Qt53DQuickRender Qt53DInput Qt53DAnimation Qt53DExtras Qt5WebChannel
To be deployed     : Qt5Concurrent Qt5Core Qt5Gamepad Qt5Gui Qt5Network Qt5Positioning Qt5PrintSupport Qt5Qml Qt5Quick Qt5QuickWidgets Qt5SerialPort Qt5Svg Qt5WebSockets Qt5Widgets Qt5WinExtras Qt5WebEngineCore Qt5WebEngineWidgets Qt53DCore Qt53DRender Qt53DQuick Qt53DQuickRender Qt53DInput Qt53DAnimation Qt53DExtras Qt5WebChannel
```

As you can see, despite windeployqt being aware of "needed" modules, it seems to deploy all Qt modules, even unused ones.
I am aware it is possible to use "--no-" option to manually exclude modules, but I want windeployqt to automatically detect and add only direct dependencies. Is there a way to limit deployed modules to bare minimum with this program?

Comment: can you show your QT+= dependencies? Is not a problem to deploy a GPL DLL,  because your software is not using it

Comment: @MiguelAngelPons turns out Qt53DQuick is NOT QtQuick 3D module library. I saw the source for Qt 5.12, and realized QtQuick 3D module is not part of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Qt53DQuick is NOT QtQuick 3D module library. Qt 5.12.x does not have QtQuick 3D module, and the dlls are part of the Qt3D module.